Is $a_n < \epsilon s_n$ for a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n)$, its partial sums $(s_n)$, and all sufficiently large $n$?
Let $a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence so that its partial sums $s_n$ tend to infinit.
I want to prove that for every positive real $\epsilon$ there is a natural number $N$ so that if $n>N$, then $a_n<$ $\epsilon *$ $s_n$, that is, it is impossible to make a sequence such as $a_n$ so that, for a given positive real $\epsilon$, every $a_n$ is greater than a given and constant fraction of its respective $s_n$.
I'm stuck at this proof, which stems from another related question:
Let $a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence so that its partial sums $s_n$ tend to infinit.
Prove that $\lim \frac{a_1+a_3+a_5+...}{a_2+a_4+a_6+...}=1$.
Currently I'm more interested in the first question, but it arose from an attempt to prove the second.

Isn't $a_n = 2^n$ a counterexample?

for which $\epsilon$?

I have tried to make the title more specific, I hope that it correctly reflects your question.

it does, thank you very much

Note that $a_n = 2^n$ satisfies $$ \frac{a_1+a_3+ \cdots + a_{2n-1}}{a_2+a_4+\cdots + a_{2n}}= \frac 12 , , $$ so that is also a counterexample to your second problem.

You suspect that if $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence of real numbers then
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n} = 0 \, ,
$$
but that is not generally true: A counterexample is $a_n = 2^n$ with
$$
 \frac{a_n}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n} = \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}-1} \to \frac 12 \, ,
$$
i.e. $a_n \sim \frac 12 s_n$ for $n \to \infty$.

Remark: The Stolz–Cesàro theorem states that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{a_n}
= 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}
$$
if the limit on the right-hand side exists. Therefore counterexamples can be constructed by finding sequences with $a_{n-1}/a_n \to L <1$, and that is how I came up with $a_n = 2^n$.
